# How to select and swipe left the particular element in the list of items in Mobile app?

Tags: android, selenium, appium

//select and swipe the particular element

```
List<WebElement> instances = driver.findElements(By.className("item-content"));

//I tried this
String instanceName=instances.get(3).getText();
for (WebElement singleInstance : instances) {
String instanceh2Text = singleInstance.getText();
if(instanceh2Text.equals(instanceName)){
Point point = singleInstance.getLocation(); 
int xcord = point.getX(); 
System.out.println("Element's Position from left side Is "+xcord +" pixels."); 
int ycord = point.getY(); 
System.out.println("Element's Position from top side Is "+ycord +" pixels.");
```

//swipe is not worked

```
JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jsx.executeScript("scrollBy(-50,0)");
WebElement startButton=driver.findElement(By.className("button-royal"));
startButton.click();
}
}
```

//the HTML code

```
<img ng-class="getRightImage(item)" src="img/Power-Button-icon.png" class="offIcon">

<h2><strong class="ng-binding">aws8 - aws sdk test</strong> <ion-spinner ng-hide="!( item.state == 'stopping' || item.state == 'pending') " style="display:inline" class="spinner spinner-ios ng-hide"> </ion-spinner>  </h2>
</div>

<div class="item-options invisible"><ion-option-button class="button-royal icon ion-play button" ng-hide="!( item.state == 'stopped') " ng-click="startInstance(item)"></ion-option-button></div>
```

//CODE FOR LIST OF ITEMS

```
    <div class="item-content"> 
<img ng-class="getRightImage(item)" src="img/Power-Button-icon.png" class="offIcon"> 
<h2><strong class="ng-binding">aws8 - aws sdk test</strong> 
<ion-spinner ng-hide="!( item.state == 'stopping' || item.state == 'pending') " style="display:inline" class="spinner spinner-ios ng-hide"> </ion-spinner>
</h2> 
</div> 
<div class="item-options invisible">
<ion-option-button class="button-royal icon ion-play button" ng-hide="!( item.state == 'stopped') " ng-click="startInstance(item)"></ion-option-button></div>
```

Comment: my HTML code   <div class="item-content">

<img ng-class="getRightImage(item)" src="img/Power-Button-icon.png" class="offIcon">

<h2><strong class="ng-binding">aws8 - aws sdk test</strong> <ion-spinner ng-hide="!( item.state == 'stopping' || item.state == 'pending') " style="display:inline" class="spinner spinner-ios ng-hide"> </ion-spinner></h2>
</div>

<div class="item-options invisible"><ion-option-button class="button-royal icon ion-play button" ng-hide="!( item.state == 'stopped') " ng-click="startInstance(item)"></ion-option-button></div>

Comment: did you try using the swipe method: driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, duration);

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried developing a swipe using the `WebElement` recently, try if this could help you :

```
/**
 * This is a test utility to swipe vertically on the screen using
 * Coordinates x,y base being top-left hand corner of element
 *
 * @param element     on the screen to swipe along its width
 * @param leftToRight being a boolean flag to point the direction of swipe
 */
public void swipeHorizontally(WebElement element, boolean leftToRight) {
    Point elementLocation = element.getLocation();
    Dimension elementDimension = element.getSize();
    int source_width = elementLocation.getX() + elementDimension.getHeight() / 2;
    int source_height = elementLocation.getY() + elementDimension.getWidth() / 2;
    int destination_width = source_width;
    int destination_height = source_height;
    if (leftToRight)
        destination_width += elementDimension.getWidth();
    else
        destination_width -= elementDimension.getWidth();
    driver.swipe(source_width, source_height, destination_width, destination_height, 0);
}
```